# Invoke an overloaded generic method on a static class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, html-helper

I'm trying to invoke methods on the [InputExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.aspx) static class in order to create overloads for the methods on the `HtmlHelper` class.

So anyway, I still couldn't invoke the methods of the `InputExtensions` class. Here's part of the code that I'm using to do so:

```
    Type inputExtensions = typeof(InputExtensions);
    MethodInfo methodInfo = null;
    MethodInfo genericMethod = null;
    switch (propertyViewingMode.ViewingLevel)
    {
        case 1:
            methodInfo = inputExtensions.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(HtmlHelper<TModel>), typeof(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>), typeof(Object) });
            genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TModel), typeof(TProperty));
            result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { helper, expression, new { @class = "readOnly", @readonly = "read-only" } }) as MvcHtmlString;
            break;
        case 2:
            methodInfo = inputExtensions.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(HtmlHelper<TModel>), typeof(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>) });
            genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TModel), typeof(TProperty));
            result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { helper, expression }) as MvcHtmlString;
            break;
        default:
            result = new MvcHtmlString(String.Empty);
            break;
    }
```

The problem is that `methodInfo` is always null, which means that `Type.GetMethod` is not finding the method I'm trying to invoke.

**UPDATE:** Note that when I do not provide the `GetMethod` method with a `Type[]` array, it throws an exception telling me that the call is ambiguous.

**UPDATE 2:** This is the method I'm trying to invoke:

```
TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, Object)
```

**ANSWER:**

```
    Type inputExtensions = typeof(InputExtensions);
    IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = null;
    MethodInfo genericMethod = null;
    MethodInfo methodInfo = null;
    switch (propertyViewingMode.ViewingLevel)
    {
        case 1:
            methods = inputExtensions.GetMethods().Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name.Equals(methodName))
                                                        .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Count() == 3);
            methodInfo = methods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetParameters()[2].ParameterType.FullName == "System.Object");
            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TModel), typeof(TProperty) });
                result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { helper, expression, new { @class = "readOnly", @readonly = "read-only" } }) as MvcHtmlString;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            methods = inputExtensions.GetMethods().Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name.Equals(methodName))
                                                        .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
            methodInfo = methods.FirstOrDefault();
            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TModel), typeof(TProperty) });
                result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { helper, expression }) as MvcHtmlString;
            }
            break;
        default:
            result = new MvcHtmlString(String.Empty);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Which method are you trying to find using GetMethod? Is it public or private? You should provide correct BindingFlags to find what you want. By default it searches only for public methods

Comment: I'm only interested in public methods anyway.

Comment: Post the signature of the method(s) you are trying to find. That would make it a lot easier.mone problem you have is that you are currently searching for public instance methods but you say you're searching for methods on a static class

Comment: @Rune FS: I updated the question. Check update 2 please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
```

Edit:

Try iterating over the methods in debug mode until you find the one you're looking for, then you can examine the params to make sure they all line up.

```
typeof(A).GetMethods().Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod);
```

Comment: Nope, did not help. Moreover, all the methods on this class are public and static.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post your model.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that it is not possible... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yirutang/archive/2005/09/14/466280.aspx

The only thing you can do is to iterate over all methods with given name and analyze argument types by yourself :(

Comment: That was one hunch :( Good to know it is not possible.

Comment: It is very strange that it is not fixed yet

Comment: You're probably right. I ended up using LINQ to find the overload that I need.

Comment: It is not really possible to fix :(

Comment: could you please clarify, why?