# Modifying HTML attributes passed to custom HtmlHelper extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm trying create a custom HTML helper extension method that takes an `object htmlAttributes` and then get the passed in values (via reflection) and add to them into a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Unfortunately, this does not work although there is an overload in the [InputExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.aspx) class that takes a `Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes` as a parameter.

The problem is that this dictionary is not being processed properly somewhere inside the razor engine (I guess...). Here's how it is being output as HTML:

```
<input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Count="3" Comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]"/>
```

And here's my code:

```
    Dictionary<String, Object> attributes = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    PropertyInfo[] properties = htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
    {                                        
        if (propertyInfo.Name.Equals("class"))
        {
            attributes.Add("class", String.Format("{0} {1}", "readOnly", propertyInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null)));
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null));
        }
    }

    genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TModel), typeof(TProperty) });
    result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { helper, expression, (Dictionary<String, Object>)attributes }) as MvcHtmlString;
```

P.S: This is a follow up to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634988/invoke-an-overloaded-generic-method-on-a-static-class)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to call the TextBoxFor method directly and pass in the expression and your new html attributes.

```
public static IHtmlString Test<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    Dictionary<String, Object> attributes = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    PropertyInfo[] properties = htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.Name.Equals("class"))
        {
            attributes.Add("class", String.Format("{0} {1}", "readOnly", propertyInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null)));
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null));
        }
    }

    //call the input tag
    return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: There's a `RouteValueDictionary` constructor overload that accepts `object` as well. No need to use reflection.

Comment: The overload for that just does the same thing but you're right that you can use that easier.

Comment: I tried to create an instance of `RouteValueDictionary` that takes the attributes dictionary, and then pass that instance as the parameter of the invoked method, but still that did not change anything! All I need to do is be able to modify the `htmlAttributes` object, so if I could get rid of the dictionary altogether that would be perfect.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem. What are you trying to return from your extension? Just the string of html attributes or the entire tag itself?